# Temporarily route stdout/stderr of a forked mongod process to console

Tags: linux, mongodb, console, stdout

I started a mongodb server instance with the following command line parameters

```
mongod --port 12345 --fork --logpath mongodb/test/logs/log.txt --dbpath mongodb/test/wiredTiger
```

How can I temporarily make this database instance write its stdout/stderr messages to my console window?

Or is it possible to connect to it via a mongo client and instruct the server to echo those messages to this client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server runs on a *nix environment you can use tail command from a terminal like so:

```
tail -f /${path}/mongodb/test/logs/log.txt
```

It will just give you a scrolling view of your log.txt file in the console screen.

Comment: I am not sure if that log actually contains all the info that would be output to stdout and stderr. It feels like some client connections are missing.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-logpath) states _--logpath <path> Sends all diagnostic logging information to a log file instead of to standard output_. So, it seems to me, all the info ends up in this file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i'm not a user of mongod, so i'm guessing here:

Mongod seems to be c++ program using `cout`, `cerr` streams, eg see [initializer.cpp:95](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/base/initializer.cpp) (that is line 95 of that file, you may need scroll down a bit)

Q: Does the `mongod` command redirect everything (stdout,stderr) to the logfile given in `logpath`? If so, maybe just remove the 'logpath' option. (haven't tested it.)

To test where the output goes, maybe try to run it with some invalid startup parameters, and see where the output goes.

Answer (score 0):

Start it without `--fork` and `--log` so that it will run in foreground and write logs to console:

```
mongod --port 12345  --dbpath mongodb/test/wiredTiger
```

This will start db on port 12345